# Visual studio 2012 Post Build EXE returns an error but not failing the build

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, build-process, checkin

I'm trying to run some exe file after my build is done that's verifies some stuff.
for this, i'm using the Post Build Hook from the build definitions and set "Treat Exe failure as build error" to true. the problem is, that after running the build, although i can see that there is an error in the build, the build status is "Partially succeded" instead of failed which is not so good since i'm trying to create a gated check-in build. can anyone knows how i'm causing the build to fail?